# WebMatrix 2 site problems on upload to host

Tags: webmatrix

I have developed a Web Pages 2 website for my company using WebMatrix 2 that includes a simple SQL Compact Edition (.sdf file) database. Sounds simple. Runs perfectly on my local development box.

However, upon FTP to my Web host, it's a no-go. The first error I received was this:

---

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  @{
Line 2:      WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Omniflow", "UserProfile", "UserId", "Email", true);
Line 3:  }
```

---

I have searched and searched and searched the Internet, trying to find out what the source of this problem is and how to fix it. I haven't found the answer yet. I gather than apparently some needed assemblies/dlls are not being uploaded with the application. I have tried both FTP and the Web Deploy method with no fix.

Is this the root of the problem? And why does WebMatrix not upload all its dependencies? If it cannot, why is there nothing in the online literature from Microsoft--and it should come from Microsoft--or anyone else describing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using one of the hosting sites listed on the Microsoft WebMatrix page: http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/ ?   I know that when I deployed my WebMatrix site to a generic IIS server, it took some extra DLL's in the bin directory, and a couple of settings to be fine tuned before it worked.

Answer (score 0):

While publishing check whether your have selected Database file( .sdf file ) or not.If not then select it and publish.
Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have all the SqlCE DLLs required for accessing the SqlCE database.
They should be present in the bin\, bin\x86\ and bin\AMD64\ folders.

You can try creating a new site using Site from Template -> Empty Site (ASP.NET) and checking the bin folder to see which all dlls are present.

If you don't already have them in your site, add them. That should solve your problem.